# Sbt test: class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger cannot be cast to class ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger (org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger

Tags: java, scala, logging, slf4j

I'm new to Scala and JVM,
I want to write unit test for logger but I get this error
when I ran `sbt test` from terminal.

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger cannot be cast to class ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger (org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger and ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger are in unnamed module of loader 'app')` 
and this warning

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/yl3/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.16.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.16.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/yl3/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.11/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

But when I ran test from IntelliJ, it passes.

My test code is below

```scala
import org.scalatest._
import flatspec._

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent
import ch.qos.logback.core.read.ListAppender
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class MyAppSuite extends AnyFlatSpec {
  it should "Log message" in {
    object MyApp {
      val LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[ILoggingEvent])
    }
    class MyApp {
      def hello(word: String): Unit = {
        MyApp.LOGGER.info(s"Word is ${word}")
      }
    }

    val appender = new ListAppender[ILoggingEvent]
    appender.start()
    val logger = MyApp.LOGGER.asInstanceOf[Logger]
    logger.addAppender(appender)

    val myApp = new MyApp
    myApp.hello("wow")

    val logsList = appender.list
    assert(logsList.size() === 1)
    val logEvent = logsList.get(0)
    assert(logEvent.getLevel.levelStr === "INFO")
    assert(logEvent.getMessage === "Word is wow")
  }
}
```

My dependencies in `build.sbt`

```
...

scalaVersion := "2.12.14"

val log4jVersion = "2.16.0"

val loggingDependencies = Seq(
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.36",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % log4jVersion,
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % log4jVersion,
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % log4jVersion
)

val testingDependencies = Seq(
  "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock" % "5.2.0" % Test,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.12" % Test,
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.11" % Test,
)

libraryDependencies ++= loggingDependencies ++ testingDependencies
excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12"
)
```

When I ran test from IntelliJ I see this warning

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/yl3/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.11/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/yl3/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.16.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.16.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

I found similar logging tests in Java

- https://mincong.io/2020/02/02/logback-test-logging-event/
- https://kotlintesting.com/mock-slf4j/

So I assume it should work in Scala but not sure why casting doesn't work.
Any suggestions or other ways to test logging using other libraries?

Comment: Wrong imports! replace `import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` with `import import org.slf4j.Logger`

Comment: @AminMal If I replace that, I get `value addAppender is not a member of org.slf4j.Logger` at the line  `logger.addAppender(appender)`

Comment: I don't know about that, the problem you mentioned in your question was because `org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger` implements `org.slf4j.Logger`, not `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger`

Comment: I added more details, also this test fails only in terminal `sbt test` but passes from IntelliJ though I see `SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings` warning in both cases

Comment: `asInstanceOf` is almost always a problem. Use `match` to make sure it really is the type you want.

Answer (score 1):

The warning messages from SLF4J are really helpful. In both cases it says **there are several logging libraries loaded in the classpath and this might cause trouble**.

When looking in details, it even says which library is chosen as the SLF4J implementation:

- in your IntelliJ tests, it chose Logback: `Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]`
- but in your SBT run it chose Log4j: `Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]`

This explains that your code that expects the logging library to be Logback works in IntelliJ tests but not with SBT run.

**When there are several logging implementation in the classpath, there's no way to know for sure which one SLF4J will use.**

---

Now, let's clarify the dependencies you have in your build definition:

- `slf4j-api`: the SlF4J API,
- `log4j-api`: the log4j 2 API,
- `log4j-core`: the log4j 2 implementation
- `log4j-slf4j-impl`: the binding to make SLF4J write logs with log4j 2 implementation
- `logback-core` and `logback-classic`: Logback implementation (Logback comes with a binding to make SLF4J write logs with Logback automatically)
  And you already excluded `slf4j-log4j12` which is the binding to make SLF4J write logs with log4j 1.2 implementation.

---

**Solution**

If you don't need several logging libraries (which is 99% of the time the case), just **choose the implementation you want to use**, it seems to be Logback as you have Logback specific code. Then **remove other libraries implementation and binding dependencies**.

This would mean to remove `log4j-core` and `log4j-slf4j-impl` in your case.

But then you might still have code that rely on the log4j 2 API to log stuff (other dependencies for instance). Thus you might need to add the binding library to make log4j 2 logs be written through SlF4J. To do so, add the `log4j-to-slf4j-2.x` dependency.

*Note: if for some strange reason you need several logging implementation, then do not assume in your code that it's one of them or handle it by handling cast exceptions.*

Comment: Thanks for the details Gael! I would like to use `logback` for testing and `log4j` for non-test (prod), so if I remove `log4j-core` and `log4j-slf4j-impl`, it passes tests but breaks when I start app :( Is there ways to specify to use logback in test (`sbt test`)? I tried like `"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.11" % Test exclude("org.a pache.logging.log4j", "log4j-slf4j-impl")` but didn't work

Comment: I will remove the logback dependency and try to create custom appender with log4j and probably create separate question if not working

Comment: Why would you want a different logger in test than in prod?

Comment: Indeed I think you're best to stick with a single logging library and work out how to test with this library.